# Proving a bound on the difference between expected value of a continuous random variable and the expected value sampled on all integers

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I need to prove that for a random variable $X$ with
$$  
X \geqslant 0
$$
it's true that
$$  
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X \geqslant n) \leqslant E[X] \leqslant 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X \geqslant n)
$$

I proved that
$$
E[X] = \int_{0}^{\infty} P(X \geqslant t) dt
$$
so I have the first part of the inequality proved by comparing the integral with the sum. I'm not sure how to go about proving the other part, i.e.
$$
E[X] \leqslant 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X \geqslant n)
$$
I was trying to move some things around and reason why $\int_{0}^{\infty} P(X \geqslant t) dt - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X \geqslant n) \leqslant 1$  but I didn't get far.
I was thinking of (somehow) using the fact that the integral of the pdf of $X$ is bounded by 1 but no luck. Any suggestions for how to get started on this?

Comment: take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the integral up and estimate the probability $P(X\ge t)$ for $t\in[n,n+1]$ from above by $P(X\ge n)$.

\begin{align*}
EX &= \int_0^1P(X\ge t)\,dt + \int_1^\infty P(X\ge t)\,dt\\
&\le 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{n}^{n+1}P(X\ge t)\,dt \\
&\le 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}P(X\ge n)\,dt \\
&= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X\ge n)
\end{align*}